# gojs apply parameter only when part of group

Tags: gojs

Using gojs, I would like to apply parameters only when the object is placed inside another object.

for example a panel should only have the padding added `(or change value, from 0 to 25)` when placed inside a  H Group.

is this possible?
looking at [gojs docs](https://gojs.net/latest/intro/events.html) I see `SelectionGrouped` but not sure if this includes dropping the object into a `H Group`

```
myDiagram.nodeTemplateMap.add("j2",
                $(go.Node, "Auto",
                    $(go.Panel, "auto", {padding:0},
                        $(go.Shape, "File"),
                        $(go.TextBlock,  "This\n is a\n file", textStyle(),
                            new go.Binding("text", "text").makeTwoWay())
                    )
                ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fire events when Parts are added to or removed from groups using `Group.memberAdded and` memberRemoved` https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Group.html#memberAdded

Or you can make a data binding on the Part (that isn't the Group) to do something different when its `containingGroup` is not null. Example binding:

```
      new go.Binding("margin", "containingGroup", function(a) {
        if (a === null) return 5;
        // otherwise its in a group:
        return 15;
      }).ofObject(),
```

See it live here:
https://codepen.io/simonsarris/pen/LYNOpme?editors=1010